# C++ измерение времени работы функции

Tags: c++, производительность

Является ли хорошей идеей измерять время затраченное на работу функции используя `std::chrono`? В данный момент пишу игровой движок и частенько прибегаю к литературе на эту тему. В одной из книг заметил, что человек рекомендует и одновременно НЕ рекомендует использовать `std::chrono` для измерения времени затраченного функцией. К сожалению, на вопрос "почему не рекомендует" - ответа так и не дал. Потому я решил обратиться на данный форум.

Для теста написал пару препроцессоров в файле инструментов, но так и не понял чем обусловлена не рекомендация использования данного подхода:

```
#define DURATION(a) std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(a).count()
#define TIME_NOW() std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()
```

Comment: Например указание наносекунд еще не значит, что точность будет именно такая. А вообще используйте профайлер.

Comment: Рекомендовал бы посмотреть [книгу Гантерота](https://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-9908910-6-7.html), там есть и о том, как время мерить и всякие плюсы-минусы... Переписывать здесь страницами как-то глупо, так что...

Answer (score 0):

```
class LogDuration {
public:
    LogDuration(std::string id)
        : id_(std::move(id)) {
    }

    ~LogDuration() {
        const auto end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        const auto dur = end_time - start_time_;
        std::cout << id_ << ": ";
        std::cout << "operation time"
                  << ": " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(dur).count()
                  << " ms" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    const std::string id_;
    const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start_time_ = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
};
```

Твоя идея нормальная, но такой код, который я тебе скинул обычно юзают через класс. Вот реализация код с хабра про мув конструкторы.